# cannot export to csv using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am retrieving data from the database and downloading the data into a csv file. the functionality is working as expected, however the csv file that is being downloaded also contains the page source code, I do not know why this is happening and have been trying for a long time. I hope someone can help me with this. below is the source code:

```
public function exportSalesCsv()
{

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . config::get('mysql/db'), config::get('mysql/username'), config::get('mysql/password'));
$sql = "SELECT 
            CONCAT(u.name, ' ', u.surname) AS salesPerson,
            t.initiation_timestamp AS saleDate,
            t.customer_account_id AS customerAccount,
            tt.transaction_type AS transactionType,
            r.resource_unique_value AS soldResource,
            CONCAT(rb.resource_brand,
                    ' ',
                    rm.resource_model,
                    ' ',
                    rt.resource_type) AS resourceModel,
            r.voucher_value_id as value
        FROM
            ims.transactions t
                INNER JOIN
            ims.resources r ON t.resource_id = r.resource_id
                INNER JOIN
            ims.resource_models rm ON r.resource_model_id = rm.resource_model_id
                INNER JOIN
            ims.resource_brands rb ON rm.resource_brand_id = rb.resource_brand_id
                INNER JOIN
            ims.resource_types rt ON rm.resource_type_id = rt.resource_type_id
                INNER JOIN
            ims.users u ON t.uid = u.uid
                INNER JOIN
            ims.transaction_types tt ON t.transaction_type_id = tt.transaction_type_id
        WHERE
            t.transaction_type_id = 3
                AND YEAR(t.initiation_timestamp) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
        UNION SELECT 
            CONCAT(u.name, ' ', u.surname) AS salesPerson,
            o.closing_timestamp AS saleDate,
            o.customer_id AS customerAccount,
            tt.transaction_type AS transactionType,
            r.resource_unique_value AS soldResource,
            CONCAT(rb.resource_brand,
                    ' ',
                    rm.resource_model,
                    ' ',
                    rt.resource_type) AS resourceModel,
            r.voucher_value_id as value
        FROM
            orders o
                INNER JOIN
            ims.users u ON o.initiation_uid = u.uid
                INNER JOIN
            ims.transaction_types tt ON o.order_type_id = tt.transaction_type_id
                INNER JOIN
            ims.resources r ON o.resource_id = r.resource_id
                INNER JOIN
            ims.resource_models rm ON r.resource_model_id = rm.resource_model_id
                INNER JOIN
            ims.resource_brands rb ON rm.resource_brand_id = rb.resource_brand_id
                INNER JOIN
            ims.resource_types rt ON rm.resource_type_id = rt.resource_type_id
        WHERE
            o.order_type_id = 4
                AND order_status_id = 1
                AND YEAR(o.closing_timestamp) = YEAR(CURDATE())";
$results = $conn->query($sql);

$response = implode(",", array('salesPerson','saleDate','customerAccount','transactionType','soldResource','resourceModel','value'));
$response .= "\n";

foreach($results as $row)
{
    $response .= implode(",",array($row['salesPerson'], $row['saleDate'], $row['customerAccount'], $row['transactionType'], $row['soldResource'], $row['resourceModel'], $row[escape('value')]));
    $response .= "\n";
}

header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=salesExport.csv');

echo $response;

return;
```

}

The following screenshot explains what I mean: [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1FeT.png)

And here is how I am invoking the method:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
include_once ("header.php");

if ($user->isLoggedIn()){

//check if user has permission
if ($user->hasPermission('reports') || $user->hasPermission('allAccess')){

    $inventory = new inventory();

    if(isset($_POST['exportSalesCsv'])){

        $inventory->exportSalesCsv();

    }...
```

Comment: And what should happen?

Comment: @u_mulder I need a prompt to popup and ask the user for the download location

Comment: Then set proper headers.

Comment: @u_mulder I`m kind of an ametaur, hence my post here, so I would appreciate your help on this matter. thanks

Comment: Don't just try to guess how functions work. Look at the examples in the documentation and, if they're obscure to you, find examples or tutorials somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Your script only saves the file to disk and is populated with data, but it is not return in the response of call

One solution if the created file is accessible by apache/nginx server you could redirect to it. Add this to the end of your function.

```
header('Location: ' . $url_to_file);
return;
```

Another solution is not to print to file but write to a variable and return it with the headers for returning a CSV file, so that the browser interprets it as a csv file:

```
$results = $conn->query($sql);

$response = implode(",", array('salesPerson','saleDate','customerAccount','transactionType','soldResource'));
$response .= "\n";

foreach($results as $row)
{
    $response .= implode(",",array($row['salesPerson'], $row['saleDate'], $row['customerAccount'], $row['transactionType'], $row['soldResource']));
    $response .= "\n";
}

header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=' . strtotime("now") . '.csv');

echo $response;

return;
```

Comment: `+=` for strings is javascript approach.

Comment: Works in PHP also.

Comment: @AlexEfimov This is very close to what I wanted, my only problem now is that for some reason the csv file consists of the source code for the page instead of the returned data from db. But the rest is what I expected to happen.

Comment: Which solution are you using? Are you trying to also write to file on disk and return the output? Or redirect?

Comment: @AlexEfimov I am trying the second solution, it works as I expected, but when I open the csv file this contains the source code along with the results returned.

Comment: @AlexEfimov In the meantime I have tried other methods but yours seems to be the closest to what I need, I just cannot get to understand why the csv file contents contain page source code

Comment: Do a var_dump on $response see if the problem is there. If not maybe you could do a die after echo

Comment: Did you succeed in removing the code from the csv file?